# Issue with Slider sometimes not loading full width

Tags: javascript, css

I've literally troubleshooted everything on this!

[View Here](http://www.cambrianvacation.co.uk/4penny/book)

Sometimes the slider is not loading full width and leaving a space to the left of about 150px. Only sometimes. If I hit Inspect Element it scales correctly.

Is this a JS issue or a CSS issue, is there a way to force full width on the slider.

I've checked all the JS and debugged turning things off and on, yet no solution, I've turned off the CSS Animations, no difference, I have a margin-left:0px!important; on the slider yet it doesn't make any difference.

Any help appreciated!!!

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a **clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask: If it is possible to create a live example of the problem that you can link to (for example, on http://sqlfiddle.com/ or http://jsbin.com/) then do so - **but also include the code in your question itself**. Not everyone can access external sites, and the links may break over time.